# Profiles for setting margin/header/footer on print from browser.

Tags: printing, browser-plugin

Sometimes I need to print a webpage without margins, header or footer.
I can set the margins manually, but then I have to reset the margins when I want to print normally.

I can select the browser which work :-)

I'd like to have a toolbar button or something to change between "printer profiles".

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of work arounds but in general, printing from browsers is poor.

The first idea would be to use the features of your printer driver to have a narrow margins setting. Some drivers support this.

You could also try overriding the print media CSS for any web page using a browser addin but you are still at the mercy of the browsers print function.

With Firefox, it *might* be possible to wright a plugin that reset the default print settings - probably overkill but likely possible! :)

Firefox also exposes it's internal CSS, see `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\res` I think. So it might be possible to hack the defaults. Not quite what you want though some further hacking using AutoHotKey or some HTA or perhaps a PowerShell script (well actually I'm assuming Windows here but you don't actually say) would give you a fairly easy way to switch. Through truthfully, I'm not sure if you would have to reload the browser after switching.

Sorry, more ideas than answer.